# Using my native node module with Electron

Tags: node.js, electron

So i have built a simple node demo module that works fine with node.exe but when i try to require it with atom electron as a module it does not work even though it was linked with the exact same version of node that my version of electron uses and it the same machine type (x86)
I have tried to use the electron source (node.dll.lib) instead but it I get v8 link errors
What is the excepted way to do this?

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall v8::HandleScope::HandleScope(class v8::Isolate *)" (??0HandleScope@v8@@QAE@PAVIsolate@1@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl node::NODE_SET_PROTOTYPE_METHOD(class v8::Local,char const *,void (__cdecl*)(class v8::FunctionCallbackInfo const &))" (?NODE_SET_PROTOTYPE_METHOD@node@@YAXV?$Local@VFunctionTemplate@v8@@@v8@@PBDP6AXABV?$FunctionCallbackInfo@VValue@v8@@@3@@Z@Z)   nodeaddon   c:\src\justin\nodeaddon\nodeaddon\myobject.obj  1

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs you'd need to [rebuild](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md) `electron` with you native module. The easiest way is to use [electron-rebuild](https://github.com/electronjs/electron-rebuild), which the team provides.

Comment: I have no idea how that works. But i ended up setting changing my linker and compiler paths to point to the electron as apposed to the node source source and at all works now. the electron rebuild thing. i think you need to have packaed your source in some way for that to work but way off that stage yet ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting changing my linker and compiler paths to point to the electron as apposed to the node source source and at all works now.